# Plugin hides element by default, can't figure out how to not

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using the [sidr](http://www.berriart.com/sidr/) jQuery plugin to create an offcanvas menu when the screen is in a certain width. However by default the plugin hides the sidebar, and I'd like to only hide it when it's in a certain screen size, such as:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    .sidebar {
        display: none !important;
        top: 50px;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 100;
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

But since the plugin hides the sidebar by default, it doesn't work. Any reason why?

Here is a live part of the website:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54191672/theme/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#menu').sidr({
    name: 'sidr-main'
});
$.sidr('open', 'sidr-main');
```

Comment: Doing that though causes the sidebar to overlap content.

Comment: That's a side effect of using position:fixed. You could either use position:relative on your sidebar, or you could offset your content with padding-left:260px(width of your sidebar).

Comment: Thanks, the plugin offers another way of doing it in their section "Open/Close Programatically". I was hoping to use this instead of adding their own CSS. How would you use this instead?

Comment: Can you share the jQuery code on how you implemented your sidebar?

Comment: The first or second line of sidr's css is "display:none;", will be visible if you delete it